# Combining Futures dependent on each other

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, concurrent.futures

I'm using Scala to make HTTP GET requests to an API (Play Framework's WS, to be exact) which responds with a JSON response that looks like;

```
{
  data: [
    {text: "Hello there", id: 1},
    {text: "Hello there again", id: 2}
  ],
  next_url: 'http://request-this-for-more.com/api?page=2' //optional
}
```

So, the `next_url` field in the returned JSON may or may not be present.

What my method needs to do is start with calling the first URL, check if the response has a `next_url` and then do a GET on that. In the end, I should have all the `data` fields from the responses combined into one single future of all the data fields. I terminate when the response has no `next_url` present in it.

Now, doing this in a blocking way is easier, but I don't want to do that. What is the best way do tackle a problem like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a method to do this somewhere in scalaz, but if you don't know a specific solution it's usually possible to construct one with recursion and `flatMap`. Something like:

```
//Assume we have an async fetch method that returns Result and Option of next Url
def fetch(url: Url): Future[(Result, Option[Url])] = ...

//Then we can define fetchAll with recursion:
def fetchAll(url: Url): Future[Vector[Result]] =
  fetch(url) flatMap {
    case (result, None) => Future.successful(Vector(result))
    case (result, Some(nextUrl)) =>
      fetchAll(nextUrl) map {results => result +: results}
  }
```

(Note that this uses a stack frame for each call - if you want to do thousands of fetches then we need to write it a little more carefully so that it's tail-recursive)

Answer (score 1):

[the Future.flatMap method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S](f:T=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]) exists exaclty for cases like that

Suppose you have such things:

```
case class Data(...)
def getContent(url:String):Future[String]
def parseJson(source:String):Try[JsValue]
def getData(value: JsValue):Seq[Data]
```

and `JsValue` type have methods inspired by [play json library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson)

```
def \ (fieldName: String): JsValue
def as[T](implicit ...):T //probably throwing exception
```

you could compose final result like

```
def innerContent(url:String):Future[Seq[Data]] = for {
  first <- getContent(url)
  json <- Future.fromTry(parseJson(first))
  nextUrlAttempt = Try((json \ "next_url").as[String])
  dataAttempt = Try(getData(json \ "data"))
  data <- Future.fromTry(dataAttempt)
  result <- nextUrlAttempt match {
    case Success(nextUrl) => innerContent(nextUrl)
    case Failure(_) => Future.successful(Seq())
} yield data ++ result
```

Also check out libraries that are targeted for complex asynchronous streams like your one:

1. [play iteratees](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.9/Iteratees)
2. [scalaz iteratees](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Iteratees.html)
3. [scalaz stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream)

Comment: Will that work for an indefinite number of `next_url`'s?

Comment: @Ashesh Sorry i didnt understood you question first. Updated my answer